# Plotting - Pch and rep functions in R

Tags: r, plot

I have completed an NMDS on biological abundances of taxa in an experiment I set up. I essentially have 3 categories that I am using in my NMDS, for simplicity sake we can just call it A, B, and C.

- A has 36 entries
- B has 35 entries
- C has 36 entries

I have no issues with the NMDS, and can get a great black and white figure that would be decent for publication. My issue is that for presentations at conferences (or for a poster) I would like to color the points to spice up the picture a bit. I am using the "rep()" function, as I am assigning symbols (and hopefully colors in the near future) to my categories.As you can see here, I can get the points solid-colored, but I think a black outline would really help make them stand out.

I have tried placing "bg=" and "col=" in places in my code that made sense, but I just cannot get a border to work. Am I missing something simple?
Here is the code, and figure I have so far.  [NMDS plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExF8v.png)

```
plot(Ulv.mds, type="n")
points(Ulv.mds$points, pch=c(rep(17, 36), rep(19, 35), rep(15, 36)),
    cex=1.1, col=c(rep("black", 36), rep("darkorange3", 35), 
    rep("purple1", 36)))
```

This is my first question, please let me know if you need any other information, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Plot your initial points slightly larger, all black, then do your colouring on top. Is one way to go about it at least. ie. first `cex` is 1.25 and your second would be 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the background `bg` option, you have to use `pch` 21 to 25. this way, you get the border you need. Int he following example, I chose colors 2:6 for the background, but you can use your formulation with `rep`.

```
plot(1:5, pch=21:25, bg=2:6, cex=2)
```

[image]

Comment: oh it's the little details.....thanks very much I have figured it out using the rep() function. My new code is this: points(Ulv.mds$points, pch=c(rep(17, 36), rep(21, 35), rep(22, 36)), cex=1.1, col=c(rep("black", 36), rep("black", 35), rep("black", 36)), bg=c(rep("black", 36), rep("darkorange3", 35), rep("purple", 36)))

Comment: Just to be clear: in your code, you are using `pch` 17, 19 and 15. This is the shape of the point. Unfortunately, these points do not accept backgrounds. Instead, you can use: 21 (round), 22 (square), 23 (lozange), 24 (upward triangle) or 25 (downward triangle).