# coloring different points in a plot

Tags: r, plot

I have

```
x1 <- runif(100,36.6,37.5)
x2 <- runif(100,37.5,38.5)
x3 <- runif(100,38.5,40)
all <- c(x1,x2,x3)
plot(all,col=c("red","yellow","blue"))
```

How can I draw `x1` with red color, `x2` with yellow and `x3` with blue?

Comment: Is there an increasingly distinct lack of marking things a duplicates these days in rstats SO? I'm guilty as charged, tho, since I'm just commenting and not doing the requisite SO search and mark as dup. This _has_ to be a dup.

Comment: I don't know.  I've tried `http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=%5br%5d%20color%20points` and can't easily find anything (perhaps because this question is so basic) - I made it through to page 3 of the results, not that I might not have missed something that was there; mostly people seem to want to color-code based on status/category, not just on position in a vector ...

Comment: Does SO have a convenient dupe-finding tool? (I know it offers a list of suggested "maybe this answers your question" previous questions when composing a new question, but I don't know if that feature is available for an already-asked question ... ?)

Comment: I see there's the "Related questions" sidebar (which doesn't seem to have anything useful in this case ...)

Comment: I also tried `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+plot+col+rep`;  some of these questions  incidentally illustrate the answer, but the question isn't really the same, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33224229/plotting-pch-and-rep-functions-in-r

Comment: maybe the trend is instead toward increasingly elementary questions that no-one has bothered asking / tried to ask before ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `col` argument is interpreted in parallel with the data vector, so you need each value to be repeated 100 times:

```
set.seed(101)    
x1 <- runif(100,36.6,37.5)
x2 <- runif(100,37.5,38.5)
x3 <- runif(100,38.5,40)
all <- c(x1,x2,x3)
plot(all,col=rep(c("red","yellow","blue"),each=100))
```

[image]